# why I still get ouput from a container process when using "-i" flag only

Tags: linux, docker

we know that `-it` is actually two flags `-i` and `-t` which means redirection from `STDIN` and `STDOUT` to the terminal repsectively.

Let's say I want to use redis-cli on a running redis container (says id is abc123) and do:

```
docker exec -i abc123 redis-cli  // only attach to `STDIN` of redis-cli process
```

when I run a valid command like `set key 1`, I got "OK" message return to my terminal. Looks like redis-cli container process can still return response("OK") to my terminal via `STDOUT`, but I didn't attach my terminal to `STDOUT`, did I?

So redis-cli container still return response to my terminal via `STDOUT`?

Comment: "-it is actually two flags -i and -t which means redirection from STDIN and STDOUT".  No, this is not a good way to think about those flags, and is the cause of your confusion.  I'm confused why you even got that idea when you can look at the man pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `t` does not mean attach STDOUT, the `t` means a pseudo TTY should be allocated, so that the container *thinks* it's writing to a TTY. Some programs have subtle differences whether they run in a TTY or not. Docker will use your terminal as TTY.

```bash
  -i, --interactive                    Keep STDIN open even if not attached
  -t, --tty                            Allocate a pseudo-TTY
```

The interactive mode alone is useful if you want to have your container read from stdin but not necessarily use your shell as pseudo TTY. For example, when writing scripts.

```
$ echo foo | docker run -i busybox cat -
foo
```

Note there is also the `attach` flag.

```bash
 -a, --attach list                    Attach to STDIN, STDOUT or STDERR
```

This might behave more like you expect from `-ti`.

Note that these two are related to each other, and docker will use defaults in some cases if certain other flags are present. This area of docker is a bit arcane and I recall some inconsistencies.

For example, one would expect when attaching STDIN directly, it would behave the same as when using the `-i` flag.
In the below example, the second docker run doesn't print the content of the file

```bash
$ echo 'hello, world' > hello.txt
$ docker run -i busybox cat < hello.txt
hello, world
$ docker run -a STDIN -a STDOUT -a STDERR busybox cat < hello.txt
```